# POST image to webserver with java c++ python

Tags: java, php, c++, html, post

I wrote an upload script in php to upload an image to my webserver.
The post request is send with a multipart/form-data html form.

Is there a way to post an image to this php script with java, c++, python, bash,...?

or if that is not possible, a way to automatically fill in the form?

Thanks.
Jon.

Answer (score 0):

You mention `bash`, why don't you try `curl?`

```
curl -F "file=@image.png" -F "yourname=Patrick" -F "filedescription=Some Desciption" http://webserver.com/url
```

Where the `-F` flag simulates filling in a form. See the [documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html) for further information on suitable flags and using `curl`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you created what is called a "[Web Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service)", and who ever is aware of the protocol of this service (i.e.: the name of the image parameter, the size restrictions, etc) can use it to upload an image to the webserver.

This can be implemented in every programming language that supports POST, that includes Java, Python, c++, and of course bash (as @BeRecursive wrote).